# Mediawiki - basic SSO script using cookies

Tags: php, cookies, single-sign-on, mediawiki

I am trying to setup a very basic SSO process between a primary site and a mediawiki site, both residing on the same domain, using cookies.

In the following example, the sites are "example.org/main", and "example.org/wiki". Users will log into "/main" only. During login to "/main" a php script will be invoked which acquires a token from "/wiki" and creates a set of 3 cookies. From this point on (as long as the session doesnt expire) the user should be able to access both sites without further logins. The assumption (for now at least) is that credentials are in sync across sites, and that sync will be managed manually.

I have tried the following script:

```
<?php
//create a cookie file
$cookie_jar = tempnam('/volume1/web/cookies','cookie'); 

//query the wiki site to get a token
$c = curl_init('http://example.org/wiki/api.php?action=query&meta=tokens&type=login&format=json');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_jar); 
$page = curl_exec($c); 

//parse the token from  the query response:
$logintoken_array = json_decode($page);
$logintoken = $logintoken_array->query->tokens->logintoken;
echo $logintoken; 

//which returns a token value like:
//"9f14c477d696fb9e63ecf5e336b071545f8f60ac+\\"

//perform action=clientlogin to log into /wiki
$post = [
    'action' => 'clientlogin',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'username' => 'dennis',
    'logintoken' => $logintoken,
    'loginreturnurl' => 'http://example.org'
];

$c = curl_init('http://example.org/wiki/api.php');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_jar); 
$page = curl_exec($c); 
curl_close($c); 
echo $page;

//this returns
//{ "clientlogin": { "status": "PASS", "username": "Dennis" }}

//then write cookies to persist the session in the browser 
$cookie_name = "test__session";
$cookie_value = $logintoken;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

$cookie_name = "test_wiki_UserID";
$cookie_value = "3";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

$cookie_name = "test_wiki_UserName";
$cookie_value = "dennis";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
?>
```

The resulting cookies are now visible in the browser's dev tool cookies listing and are identical to the 3 cookies that are created when one manually logs directly into mysite.org/wiki using the same username (except for having a different token value).

However when I in the same browser (either same tab or different tab) try to access a wiki page, the wiki page shows "not logged in" and the session and UserID cookies disappear. (Only the UserName cookie remains). I tried tweaking the cookies with samesite= "lax" but that didn't change anything.

Is there a way to make the cookies persist?

Thanks in advance,

Dennis

Versions: PHP 7.2  /  Mediawiki 1.34.4

Comment: You will probably need some coding on MediaWiki side: see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SessionManager_and_AuthManager/Linked_accounts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alexander. Is your recommendation based on the fact that the approach described in my question simply is not fixable/feasible, or is it that you believe that a more fullblown approach is more secure and appropriate? The reason I ask is that the 2 sites will be used by a limited audience of a few dozen family members for genealogical research and documentation and not really be exposed to "the general public"

Comment: Your approach may be fixable, but not reliably. If even it succeeds, it'll be a hack, and it can stop working after *MediaWiki* upgrade.

Comment: Why would you try to overwrite the same cookies that MediaWiki sets?